# Какой тип задавать функции внутри класса typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, типы, typescript-типы

Переписываю js на ts и столкнулся с проблемой типизации функций в классе.
Имеется родительский класс, в данном классе массив, в который, соответсвенно, пушатся функции вызывающиеся по подписке.

```
export default class EventEmitter {
    constructor () {
        this._handlers = []
    }

    addChangeEventListener(handler) {
        this._handlers.push(handler)
    }

    executeHandlers() {
        this._handlers.forEach((handler) => {
            handler()
        })
    }
}
```

Вопрос собственно такой: не пойму какой класс указать переменной handler и соответственно типу данных в массиве.
Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать тип `Function`, тип для массива `Array<Function>`.

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. всегда можно указать `any`
2. поскольку это массив, то можно указать `Array<any>`

Comment: any же костыль, все в один голос говорят, что использовать any - не комильфо

Comment: согласен конечно, но для перевода можно использовать, а потом уже сужать типизацию

Comment: не указать тип почти то же самое, что и `any`. Смысла особого нету.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не почти то же самое, а просто то же самое. Если тип не указывается, он по умолчанию `any` считается

Answer (score 0):

Если ваши функции имеют определенный набор аргументов, то можно указать точно

```
    addChangeEventListener(handler:(a:number, b: number)=>number) {
        this._handlers.push(handler)
    }
```

Или, если будет использоваться в нескольких местах, то можно создать тип

```
    type myFunc = (a: number, b: number) => number;
    addChangeEventListener(handler: myFunc) {
        this._handlers.push(handler)
    }
```